# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined al querer pasar valor de un select en handleChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un problema al querer mandar un valor de un select/dropdowlist  a handleChange ya que cuando cambio de valor me da el error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

aquí esta mi `handleChange`

```
  handleChange =  (e) => {
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
    console.log(this.state.form);
  };
```

Y aquí esta el de mi `dropdownlist`

```
 <br />
        <label>Categoria</label>
       
          <Select
               
                name="categoria_id"
                id="categoria_id"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.categoria.map((cate)=>{
                  if (cate.id === form.categoria_id)
                  {
                    return {
                        value : cate.id,
                        label : cate.Nombre
                          }
                  }else{
                    return{
                      value : "",
                       label : ""
                    }
                 }
                 
                 })}
                //{label:"Otros",value:1}
                options={this.state.categoria.map((cate)=>{
                 return {
                   value : cate.id,
                   label : cate.Nombre
                 }
                 })
                }
                
             >
             
               </Select>
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con esto

Comment: Porque estas manejando de forma asíncrona el `change`? Y que función cumple `e.persist()` ?

Comment: Perdon era una falla con lo de e.persist() y la funcion asyncrona que me di cuenta pero lo que entiendo es que event  no esta funcionando cuando hago un onChange con el Select

Comment: cuando tengas estos problemas de `undefined` yo te sugiero que hagas un debug para ver que es lo que tiene tu variable (que valores, que estas enviando, que atributos y que funciones), en este caso también puedes hacerlo por medio de un `console.log(e);` o un `console.log(e.target);`, si no sabes debugear, apenas entrar a la función de `handleChange()` para que veas que tienes ahí, si sigues sin encontrar el error, puedes agrega a tu pregunta lo que imprime el `console.log()` acerca de tu variable.

Comment: @Diego-1743  Segun lo que revise es que los valores se están enviando solo por el event pero y no tengo en esa name por eso me sale error pero entonces tines alguna idea de como usar este Select-react o como de como hacer este dropdown de otra manera gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Que librería estas usando para construir ese select?

Comment: Hola @PauloUrbanoRivera estor haciendo con react-select